# How to get the list of columns of same datatype from datatable

Tags: c#, datatable

i am having a datatable in my program, i want to get the list of the columns which has same data type.

i used the following code:

```
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("col1", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("col2", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("col3", typeof(int));
        dt.Columns.Add("col4", typeof(string));

        List<DataColumn> string_type_columns = new List<DataColumn>();
        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count;i++ )
        {
            if (dt.Columns[i].DataType.ToString().Equals("System.String"))
            {
                string_type_columns.Add(dt.Columns[i]);
            }
        }
```

string_type_columns will give me the list of the columns which has string datatype. 
but in my actual program there can be more than 40 columns in my table so i don't want to loop through each column of datatable.

is there any other (better) way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want less code I suppose you could use LINQ.

```
var string_type_columns = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Where(c => c.DataType == typeof(String));
```